# Change content of divs separately

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to add some content inside my divs on hover, but not the CSS way.

```js
function hover(description){
  console.log(description);
  document.getElementById('first-item').innerHTML = description;
  document.getElementById('second-item').innerHTML = description;
}
```

```css
.slide {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<?php
  $content = "some text";
?>

<div>
  <div>
    <div class="slide" id="first-item" onmouseover="hover('<?php echo $content; ?>')" onmouseout="hover('')"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="second-item" onmouseover="hover('<?php echo $content; ?>')" onmouseout="hover('')"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="third-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want **only** the content of the `.first-item` to change when I hover it and **only** the content of the `.second-item` to change when I hover it. But as you can see when I hover either one, the content of both changes.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like you don't need to pass `$content` to your function, you can just read it inside it. Instead, you can pass `this` which will give you the actual element that is hovered over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `this` as a element reference in `hover` function for both mouse in and mouse out so that you can then use this reference in JavaScript to set `innerHTML` of that particular element:

```js
function hover(elem, description) {
  elem.innerHTML = description;
}
```

```css
.slide {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
      <div class="slide" id="first-item" onmouseover="hover(this, 'sampleText')" onmouseout="hover(this, '')"></div>
      <div class="slide" id="second-item" onmouseover="hover(this, 'sampleText')" onmouseout="hover(this, '')"></div>
      <div class="slide" id="third-item" onmouseover="hover(this, 'sampleText')" onmouseout="hover(this, '')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about passing an element as a parameter of the function?

```html
<style>
    .slide {
        background:blue;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        float:left;
        margin:10px;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div>
        <div class="slide" id="first-item" onmouseover="hover(this, 'MyContent')" onmouseout="hover(this, '')"></div>
        <div class="slide" id="second-item" onmouseover="hover(this, 'MyContent')" onmouseout="hover(this, '')"></div>
        <div class="slide" id="third-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function hover(element, description) {
        console.log(description);
        element.innerHTML = description;
    }
</script>
```

The "this" refers to the current element, that way you are able to choose what will be displayed

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your `hover()` function:

```js
function hover(description) {
    console.log(description);
    document.getElementById('first-item').innerHTML = description;
    document.getElementById('second-item').innerHTML = description;
}
```

This will fill **both** of the divs with with the given content, since you don't make a difference which div should be filled with content. However, you can pass `this` as an argument of your function, so you will always just modify the element you are currently hovering:

```js
function hover(element, description) {
    console.log(description);
    element.innerHTML = description;
}
```

The you just have to change your HTML markup the following way:

```html
<div>
    <div class="slide" id="first-item" onmouseover="hover(this, '<?php echo $content; ?>')" onmouseout="hover(this, '')"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="second-item" onmouseover="hover(this, '<?php echo $content; ?>')" onmouseout="hover(this, '')"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="third-item"></div>
</div>
```